# Strange stretching problems

Tags: rendering

So while making some clothing im blender, this strange thing happened to the model. The bottom of the model stretched towards the floor. It happened after editing both of them in edit mode.

[image: edit mode]

[image: object mode]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Could you share the .blend file for us to check? This normally happens when modifying a mesh with cloth simulations, especially when adding new vertices.